# Collection of .gz files are corrupt by a very small number of bytes at very specific offsets

Tags: compression, gzip, 7zip

I have a large number of files, all in the same file format, which was sometimes gzipped for space conservation. I am curating the archive to eliminate duplicates.

For a significant number of the duplicate files (pairs of one gzipped, one regular), they differ by < 20 bytes, starting at one of a small number of file offsets (one offset being 313656 bytes from start of file; another far more common offset being 176287). Files are anywhere from 1MB to 200MB, uncompressed.

I believe Ubuntu Linux versions of gzip and/or 7zip command line utilities were used to compress the files. I cannot even be certain that the gzipped versions are the corrupt ones.

Does anyone know of a mechanism that would create such a specific pattern of corruption, which I can then (a) avoid in future and (b) hopefully use to choose the "correct" (most likely uncorrupted) version of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you decompress the gzip member of the pair, you are seeing a few bytes different from the already uncompressed other member of the pair? If so, then the next question is: did the gzip decompression work with no error message? If so, then the CRC-32 value at the end of the gzip file, as well as the uncompressed length, checked out as ok. In that case, the gzip file is the one you should keep.

I have no way of knowing or guessing what could have caused the corruption of the uncompressed files.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I was unaware that gzip uses CRC in that way. I have also confirmed that the files are different due to legitimate processing at some point in the pipeline before they got to me. They are all valid, just with different processing timestamps. (So I can safely throw one of them away. Hooray?)